# How to break the text of long text area field in vf page

Tags: css, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l69Y.png)

I have fetched the data of long text area field on my vf page how can i break the text in vf page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a Visualforce-specific question, consider changing the tags to CSS and you'll attract experts. Lots of options you can experiment with, have you seen these?

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

if the text contains `<br>` or newlines you could even wrap it in `<pre>` tags...

What's your VF page structure? Do you use `<apex:outputField>` for that or `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`? these should enforce some wrapping too. If you have raw `{!myField}` in the page then well, wrapping (and protecting from XSS injection!) is on you...

Comment: I'm using the {!myField} and i try to use the css that you are shared but the text that i attached in the image is not break.

Comment: Post your code. It's hard to guess what you've tried / in what VF page tag you need it. `<div style="width:200px;border:1px solid red;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
    </div>` works like a charm for me